# VB.NET How to avoid first key press when captured it as hotkey?

Tags: vb.net

I managed to make my app capture any key to use it as a hotkey, but when I press the key the hotkey function is activated. This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub tmrFunc_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrFunc.Tick
  'Function
End Sub

Private Sub tmrKey_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrKey.Tick
  'Uses the hotkey to start and stop tmrF
End Sub

Private Sub lblCapKey_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblCapKey.Click
    tmrKey.Enabled = False
    txtbStartFunc.Enabled = True
    txtbStartFunc.Text = "Press any key"
    txtbStartFunc.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub txtbStartFunc_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtbStartFunc.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F10 Then
        txtbStartFunc.Text = "F10"
    End If
    tmrKey.Enabled = True
    txtbStartFunc.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

The current code perfectly captures the key and uses it as a hotkey, the problem is that the hotkey is activated on this first key pressed and that causes it to be activated unexpectedly at the wrong time.

My current goal is that the function is not activated with the first keystroke, but is activated with the following keystrokes.

I am expecting something like this:

```
Private Sub txtbStartFunc_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtbStartFunc.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F10 Then
        txtbStartFunc.Text = "F10"
    End If
    tmrKey.Enabled = True
    '=========================
    tmrFunc.Enabled = False
    '=========================
    txtbStartFunc.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I don´t get your use of timers here, you could just register the hotkey via User32.dll. Anyway, just create a class bool variable to capture the first key stroke.

Comment: Instead of enabling "tmrKey" in KeyDown(), try enabling it in KeyUp()?  This way the timer will start AFTER the key has been fully release and it shouldn't trigger until it is pressed again...

Comment: I already tried that, but it triggers anyway. That's exactly why I try to stop the tmrFunc after I start the tmrKey, it still doesn't work.

Comment: What does trmFunc have to do with your hotkey, though?  All it's doing is updating the cursor position.  It's hard to follow what exactly is happening without rebuilding this ourselves.  Can you post a screenshot of your interface and then DESCRIBE the FLOW of how a user sets a "hotkey"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that finally worked for me.  It allows you to set the hotkeys between F1 and F10, but won't let you select the same key for both of them.

[image]

This is pretty different than what you had, so take your time studying it and ask as many questions as need be:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Const KeyDownBit As Integer = &H8000

    Private Enum HotKeyType
        StartClicker
        StopClicker
    End Enum

    Private _StartHotkey As Keys
    Private _StopHotKey As Keys
    Private SelectingHotKey As HotKeyType
    Private HotKeySelected As Boolean = False
    Private _SettingHotKey As Boolean = False
    Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKeys As Integer) As Short

    Private Property StartHotKey As Keys
        Get
            Return _StartHotkey
        End Get
        Set(value As Keys)
            If value <> StopHotKey Then
                _StartHotkey = value
                TextBox1.Text = StartHotKey.ToString
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Property StopHotKey As Keys
        Get
            Return _StopHotKey
        End Get
        Set(value As Keys)
            If value <> StartHotKey Then
                _StopHotKey = value
                TextBox2.Text = StopHotKey.ToString
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Property SettingHotKey As Boolean
        Get
            Return _SettingHotKey
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If value Then
                HotKeySelected = False
                Timer2.Stop()
            Else
                Timer2.Start()
            End If
            _SettingHotKey = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.KeyPreview = True
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Timer2.Enabled = False
        Timer1.Interval = 50
        Timer2.Interval = 50

        TextBox1.ReadOnly = True ' they just stay this way all the time
        TextBox2.ReadOnly = True ' they just stay this way all the time

        StartHotKey = Keys.F1
        StopHotKey = Keys.F2
        Timer2.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Dim startKeyDown, stopKeyDown As Boolean

        GetAsyncKeyState(StartHotKey) ' disregard first call to "flush it"
        startKeyDown = (GetAsyncKeyState(StartHotKey) And KeyDownBit) = KeyDownBit ' see if it's down
        GetAsyncKeyState(StopHotKey) ' disregard first call to "flush it"
        stopKeyDown = (GetAsyncKeyState(StopHotKey) And KeyDownBit) = KeyDownBit ' see if it's down

        TextBox1.BackColor = If(startKeyDown, Color.Green, Control.DefaultBackColor)
        TextBox2.BackColor = If(stopKeyDown, Color.Green, Control.DefaultBackColor)

        If startKeyDown Then
            Timer1.Start()
        End If
        If stopKeyDown Then ' if you hold both down, then it'll stop
            Timer1.Stop()
            Label1.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BothButtons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click
        SelectingHotKey = If(sender Is Button1, HotKeyType.StartClicker, HotKeyType.StopClicker)
        SettingHotKey = True ' automatically turns off Timer2
        Dim tb As TextBox = If(sender Is Button1, TextBox1, TextBox2)
        tb.Text = "Press F1 to F10"
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        Select Case keyData
            Case Keys.F1 To Keys.F10
                If SettingHotKey Then
                    If SelectingHotKey = HotKeyType.StartClicker Then
                        If keyData <> StopHotKey Then
                            StartHotKey = keyData
                            HotKeySelected = True
                            Return True
                        End If
                    Else
                        If keyData <> StartHotKey Then
                            StopHotKey = keyData
                            HotKeySelected = True
                            Return True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
        End Select
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
        If SettingHotKey AndAlso HotKeySelected Then
            SettingHotKey = False ' restarts Timer2 once selected key has been released
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Green
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff") ' just to show it's "clicking"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, here's a little example of my program, which shows my problem.

This is the interface:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lrzI.png)

When I press F1, the counter starts to add 1 to itself, when I press F2, the counter stops. The Select button changes F1 to F9 or F2 to F10, but when I change the key the function is triggered, that is, if the counter is stopped, and the key is at F1, when I click Select to change from F1 to F9, the counter is activated.

Here is an example of the code, so you can see the problem first hand:

```
Public Class Form1
    Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKeys As Integer) As Short
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Text += 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Dim a, b As Boolean

        If TextBox1.Text = "F1" Then
            a = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F1)
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "F9" Then
            a = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F9)
        End If

        If TextBox2.Text = "F2" Then
            b = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F2)
        ElseIf TextBox2.Text = "F10" Then
            b = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F10)
        End If

        If a = True Then
            Timer1.Start()
        ElseIf b = True Then
            Timer1.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer2.Enabled = False
        TextBox1.ReadOnly = False
        TextBox1.Text = "Press any key"
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        If TextBox1.ReadOnly = False Then
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.F9 Then
                TextBox1.Text = "F9"
            Else
                TextBox1.Text = "F1"
            End If
        End If
        Timer2.Enabled = True
        TextBox1.ReadOnly = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Timer2.Enabled = False
        TextBox2.ReadOnly = False
        TextBox2.Text = "Press any key"
        TextBox2.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        If TextBox2.ReadOnly = False Then
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.F10 Then
                TextBox2.Text = "F10"
            Else
                TextBox2.Text = "F2"
            End If
        End If
        Timer2.Enabled = True
        TextBox2.ReadOnly = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

@Idle_Mind

Comment: This really should have been an edit above in your original question.  (*I did not down-vote you, though.)  What are the Interval on your timers?

Comment: 1ms both,,,,,,,

Comment: I've built a test project and played with it some, but I'm confused as to what this actually does, and more importantly, how is it supposed to be used.  Can you explain, in the bigger context of your application, what this is accomplishing?  There might be a better way to do this...

Comment: I understood you, I'm creating an autoclicker, and all this is about how to change the hotkeys to whatever the user needs, but I have a problem, the problem is that the autoclicker keeps on activating when pressing the first key after choosing it, it's very simple, I guess you already rebuilt my code and you noticed the failure when choosing the key, it keeps on activating itself even if I'm just choosing the key.

Comment: Ok...so they need to click the button before setting the key right?  Then AFTER that, pressing the key should start and/or stop the timer.  So Timer2 is for detecting the keypress, and Timer1 would actually be doing the "clicking" (not really changing a Label)?

Comment: Exactly, that's basically what my app does, but with that little key problem.